# Select Field controlling Character Limit

Tags: php, jquery, html, variables, select

Does anyone know how to allow this character countdown to be controlled by pre-determined variables that are linked to the select field options?

```
var large = 300
var medium = 200
var small = 100
```

I appreciate any input greatly.

*Example Code:*

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>

function updateCountdown() {
    var remaining = 50 - jQuery('#post').val().length;
    jQuery('#character_limit').text(remaining + ' characters remaining.');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    updateCountdown();
    $('#post').change(updateCountdown);
    $('#post').keyup(updateCountdown);
});

</script>
<textarea id="post" cols="40" rows="3" maxlength="500"></textarea>
<div id="character_limit"></div>

<select name="product" id="product">
<option value="large">Large Product</option>
<option value="medium">Medium Product</option>
<option value="small">Small Product</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by firstly changing the options of the `select` element to have a value equal to the length required by that type of product:

```
<select name="product" id="product">
    <option value="300">Large Product</option>
    <option value="200">Medium Product</option>
    <option value="100">Small Product</option>
</select>
```

From there you can retrieve the selected value (converting it to a number) before subtracting the number of used characters. Also note that you would also now need to update the count on the `change` event of the `#product` field. Try this:

```
function updateCountdown() {
    var charLimit = parseInt($product.val(), 10)
    var remaining = charLimit - jQuery('#post').val().length;
    jQuery('#character_limit').text(remaining + ' characters remaining.');
}

var $product = $('#product');
updateCountdown();
$('#post, #product').change(updateCountdown);
$('#post').keyup(updateCountdown);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/47obxcou/)

Comment: That worked great! Thanks Rory!

Is there a way to lock it when it hits 0 Character limits?

Since it's changing the value based on the select, I'm not sure how to apply a character limit within the text field that runs off the select box as well.